# Why won’t my list automatically update when elements are added to an array?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I’m new to Swift, and I’m making a dice roller app for Dungeons and Dragons. I want a user’s previous dice rolls (stored in `Roll` objects that have IDs as strings) to be able to be seen in a refreshable `List`. I’m storing all the user’s dice rolls in an array, and want the list to automatically update when a new element is added to the array.

Here’s my code:

Roll.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct Roll: Identifiable {
    var id: String {"\(numDice)d\(typeDice), mod of \(modifier) = \(totalValue)"};
    @State var numDice: Int;
    @State var modifier: Int;
    @State var totalValue: Int;
    @State var typeDice: Int;
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

var rolls: [Roll] = [];

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var diceModifier: Int = 0;
    @State var numDice: Int = 1;
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Stepper(value: $diceModifier, in: -10...15, step: 1) {
                    if (diceModifier >= 0) {
                        Text("Modifier: +\(diceModifier)")
                    }
                    else {
                        Text("Modifier: \(diceModifier)")
                    }
                }
                Stepper(value:$numDice, in: 1...15, step: 1) {
                    Text("# of Dice: \(numDice)")
                }
            }
            HStack {
                Image("Logo")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                HistoryView()
            }
            ButtonView()
        }
    }
    
    struct ButtonView: View {
        let rows = [
            GridItem(.fixed(30), spacing: 10),
            GridItem(.fixed(30), spacing: 10),
            GridItem(.fixed(30), spacing: 10)
        ]
        var body: some View {
            LazyHGrid(rows: rows) {
                DiceButton(diceType: 4) // DiceButton class calls rollDice function when pressed
                DiceButton(diceType: 6)
                DiceButton(diceType: 8)
                DiceButton(diceType: 10)
                DiceButton(diceType: 12)
                DiceButton(diceType: 20)
                Spacer()
                DiceButton(diceType: 100)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func rollDice(dt: Int) -> Int {
        // .. get random number, then make a Roll object and add it to rolls
        
        var total: Int = 0;
        for _ in 1...numDice {
            let addNum = Int.random(in: 1...dt)
            total += addNum;
        }
        
        let newRoll = Roll(numDice: numDice, modifier: diceModifier, totalValue: total, typeDice: dt)
        rolls.append(newRoll)
        print(newRoll.id)
        
        return total;
    }
    
}

struct HistoryView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Your Previous Rolls").bold()
            List {
                // it will show the previous rolls, but only when I update the string in line 76 - why?
                ForEach(rolls, id: \.id) { r in
                    Text(r.id)
                }
            }
            .refreshable(action: {
                rolls = rolls
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A global property on the top level like `rolls` is bad practice and the wrong approach anyway. Either declare it in the top view as `@State` or encapsulated as `@Published` in an`ObservableObject`. Then it will notify the view to update.

Comment: `@State` is only for SwiftUI Views not regular `struct`s. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Answer (score 0):

You don’t tell anyhow to SwiftUI that `rolls` has been updated. You can either make it part of your `ContentView` with `@State` declaration, or you can for example make it an `ObservableObject` that you will observe in the view.